# Create a new column stores Complete Row as dictionary in pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe like given in snapshot

[image]

I want to add another column lets calls it "row_dict" which will store complete row as dictionary in it. Output it shown in second excel.

How can we achieve it ?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Thx!

Comment: @werner Sure ... Going forward I will post working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/sql/index.html#map) to create a map column:

```python
df = ...
expr = "map(" + ",".join([f"'{c}',`{c}`" for c in df.columns]) + ")"
df.withColumn("row_dict", F.expr(expr)).show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `create_map` function by passing the key name and the value based on each column:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Mocking DataFrame to test it.
d = [
 {"account_number": 1, "v1": 1000, "v2": 1000},
 {"account_number": 2, "v1": 2000, "v2": None}
]

# Creating mocked DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)

df = (
    df.withColumn(
       "row_dict", 
        F.create_map(
           F.lit("account_number"), 
           F.col("account_number"), 
           F.lit("v1"), 
           F.col("v1"), 
           F.lit("v2"), 
           F.col("v2"))
        )
)

df.show()
```

Depending on the amount of columns you have in your DataFrame, you can try to automate the create_map:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

d = [
 {"account_number": 1, "v1": 1000, "v2": 1000},
 {"account_number": 2, "v1": 2000, "v2": None}
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(d)

# Gets the DataFrame Columns
df_cols = df.columns

create_map_args = []

# Generates the Key -> Value pair 
_temp_map_args = [(F.lit(col), F.col(col)) for col in df_cols]

# Flattens the previous list so create_map can accept
for element in _temp_map_args: 
   create_map_args.extend(list(element))

df = df.withColumn("row_dict", F.create_map(*create_map_args))

df.show()
```

Then you can update the automation to your use case, but this is one of the ways to transform columns into a map.